# How does the Michelson interferometer measure the self-coherence function of coherent light in an incoherent background?

Tags: electrical-engineering, optics, lasers

How does the Michelson interferometer measure the self-coherence function of coherent light in an incoherent background? [*Detection of coherent light in an incoherent background* (Coutinho et al., 1999)](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/2670/) is still the best analysis and implementation of this concept despite considerable progress in semiconductor fabrication and photonics since its publication.

The reason I ask this question is because airplane pilots need to see the landing strip, ground landmarks and the horizon while at the same time harmful visible light laser rays are filtered.

Comment: Your last paragraph has absolutely nothing to do with interferometers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you change the relative arm lengths of a Michelson interferometer, the transmission (or reflection) coefficient of the interferometer ranges from $T=0$ to $T=1$ for coherent light, but, if designed properly, will always have a transmission of $T=0.5$ for incoherent light.

If we define the length of the two arms of the Michelson to be $L_1$ and $L_2+\delta\ell$, where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are macroscopic distances on the order of meters and $\delta\ell$ is a microscopic distance on the order of micrometers, then the interference properties of the Michelson only depend on $\delta\ell$ for highly coherent light like a laser.  However, the interference properties of the Michelson for incoherent light depend on the relative macroscopic distances.  If $|L_1-L_2|\gg L_c$, where $L_c$ is the [coherence length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length) of the incoherent light, then the Michelson will not display any interference regardless of $\delta\ell$.

Comment: Did you mean to write  L2 = L1 + δℓ? I would like to extend your analysis where L1 and L2 are macroscopic distances on the order of centimeters so we could miniaturize Coutinho et al's Michelson interferometer to sit directly on the top edge of a Boeing 737 cockpit window. Is is possible to do that? Finally, how do I modify your supern analyis to take into account the angle of incidence? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Frank No, it is important that L1+L2 not be equal for incoherent light to be unaffected by interferometer.  The difference in length between them must be greater than the coherence length of the incoherent light (~few mm) in order to work.  I do not believe that this will be an effective tool for your application because you will have to hold the interferometer at a point of destructive interference for the coherent light which is different for each wavelength that you might want to reflect.

Comment: Thank you for your high quality comment.With regard, to your statement " I do not believe that this will be an effective tool for your application ", are you implying that it is physically impossible to build a tunable interferometer (i.e hardware) over the RGB wavelengths? If it is impossible to build such hardware, could we resort to digital signal processing software to cancel the coherent laser pointer beam?

Comment: @Frank You might be able to use DSP techniques to detect the wavelength of the laser and lock the interferometer to reject that particular wavelength.

Comment: @ChrisMueller but you can't lock a wavelength **and** all possible entrance angles.

Comment: @Carl That is true, but you might to be able to lock it to a specific wavelength and entrance angle automatically.  What I'm imagining is an algorithm that dithers the Michelson back and forth looking for significant coherent sources and then tries to lock to a dark fringe for any coherent source (with a specific wavelength and entrance angle) it finds.

Comment: @Chris Mueller, Thank you for your very professional and creative comments, I will get back to you by 8:00PM tonight with one or two questions.

Comment: @Chris Mueller, Which dark fringe of the coherent source should we lock to? How do we lock the  lock the interferometer to reject that particular wavelength? Thank you.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, Could you please  comment on the Fourier transform and the interferogram? What are the advantages of the Coherent Inc. laser power detector,https://www.coherent.com/products/?776/EnergyMax-Laser-Sensors, over  the Michelson interfermometer? Thank you.

Comment: @Chris Mueller, I just added an answer to this question based on your analysis. Please comment on it if you have time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the dark fringe of the coherent source to lock to is the first order because the self coherence function's first minimum corresponding to the sinc function's  envelope is located at an interval of lambda\4 multiplied by the distance d where lambda equals wavelength and d is equal to the distance between a fixed mirror's image and an moving mirror's image.

The information of the greatest interest is the spectrum in one branch of the interferometer called the interferogram's inverse Fourier transform. As a result,
the interferometer's signal as a function of the optical path difference and the spectrum as a function of wavenumber, also known as 1/wavelength,form a Fourier transform pair.

If you wish to explore this topic, please read chapter 6 , Fourier Trahsform Spectroscopy , in the book written by the Finnish professors, J. Kauppinen and J. Partanen , titled Fourier Transforms in Spectroscopy.

I enjoyed chatting with the New York genius expert, @Chris Mueller , about this topic.

Thank you